# Question regarding use of recursion and use of variables

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, recursion

I wrote this recursive function that was behaving odd, it took me a few hours to get it working. I use it to traverse a JSON object, like a tree structure, searching for nodes that have a value under schedulePoint. I noticed something that left me a little confused and was hoping someone could shed some light on why. I commented the code below, where the issue was. To me, at least logically, it doesn't look different. Yet, when I used the commented out code instead, the recursion would not complete, I kept getting an empty array. It would go through one subtree, then it would empty the array before starting the next. I would just like to know what effect does using the variable have on the recursion. Any help would be appreciated. It's written in DGScript, which is some scripting language similar to javascript. Also, if there is anything you see that is redundant, or could be written more efficiently, I would appreciate the advice.

```
function findSchedules(name, jsonNode)
{
  if (hasChildren(jsonNode) == false)
  {
    data = csvToJSON(jsonNode['?value']);
    dataPath = data['dataPath'];
    schedulePoint = data['schedulePoint'];

    if (schedulePoint != "" && schedulePoint != null && schedulePoint != "NO SCHEDULE")
      return [[name, dataPath, csvToJSON(jsonNode['?value'])['schedulePoint']]];
    else
      return [];
  }

  schedules = [];

  for (node in jsonNode)
  {
    if (isValidNode(node) == true)
      schedules = schedules.concat(findSchedules(node, jsonNode[node]));
      /*
          If instead I wrote:

          if (isValidNode(node) == true)
          {
            prevSchedules = findSchedules(node, jsonNode[node]);
            schedules = schedules.concat(prevSchedules);
          }

          which is what I had originally, the recursion would not work correctly. Why are these two 
          statements different?
      */
  }

  data = csvToJSON(jsonNode['?value']);
  dataPath = data['dataPath'];
  schedulePoint = data['schedulePoint'];

  if (schedulePoint != "" && schedulePoint != null && schedulePoint != "NO SCHEDULE")
    schedules.push([name, dataPath, schedulePoint]);

  return schedules;
}
```

Comment: You need to declare your variables.  Without a `const`, `let`, or `var` declaration of `data`, `dataPath`, `schedulePoint`, and, most importantly here, `schedules`, they become global variables, so when in the recusive call you do `schedules = []`, you've reset it for the outer call as well.  Try adding `let` before the initial use of these, and see if it fixes it.

Comment: In this scripting language, I don't believe I can use let, or const, but I can use var to declare the variable. Ill give it a try, not sure how the scope matters here though, the recursion actually occurs below that line, in the for loop. Also, the way it is written written right now works, wouldn't it have the same effect, that is resetting the schedules variable? Thank you for your input, I didnt consider the scope of the variables, and that very might well be the reason. I'm just trying to better understand.

Comment: It may seem odd not to, but in DG Lux, it uses this visual type  block programming. I use a script block and write my code in it. Every time that block is invoked it runs the script once. I was under the impression that the scope of the variable is to the function/or block it was written in and have therefor developed the bad habit of not declaring my variables with var.

Comment: @essentialz if you test the not working version (that updates the `prevSchedules =`) then what does **debugging** say about it? It might be **null** and hence after the concat you get a zero length.  Debug with : `print("prevSchedules is : ", prevSchedules);` or replace **print** with **printConsole** if testing in a browser.

Comment: I'm afraid I know little about Actionscript and have never even heard of DGScript, but that is how this would work in older JS environments.  It wouldn't even compile in strict environments because of the undeclared variables.  But if the environment allows you to add, say `var` to those declarations, I would suggest trying it and seeing if it helps.

Comment: I was suggesting that `prevSchedules = findSchedules(node, jsonNode[node])`, which recurred on `findSchedules` then would reset `schedules` to `[]` and then `schedules = schedules.concat(prevSchedules)` would mean that `schedules` contains only the latest list seen.  I guess that since you already have a work-around, this is not top priority, but it seems a very likely guess.

Comment: @ScottSauyet you are right, one way or another, it is definitely the scope. I declared my variables with var and it works both ways. Still not understanding why:

    prevSchedules = findSchedules(node, jsonNode[node]);

doesnt update schedules, it updates prevSchedules. and:

    schedules = schedules.concat(prevSchedules)

shouldn't override schedules. If prevSchedules is empty, then it should just stay as it is.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. Yea, that makes sense. I appreciate your help @ScottSauyet. I'll be sure not to ignore the scope and declare my variables accordingly. I was being lazy, and paid with 4 hours of debugging. I appreciate it.